# Is there a way to use jooq between method(or something similar) to work with nullable dates?

Tags: java, kotlin, jooq

I'm trying to generate BETWEEN condition for two dates(from, to). one of them can be null and i'm forced to use lessThan, greaterThan instead of between in such case. is there another way?

tried to use standard jooq's between() method

Comment: If the date is null, could you not set 01.01.1970 for the past? And for the future the 31.12.9999? Then you could also use the between() method, right?

Answer (score 0):

There's a pending feature request for a synthetic `BETWEEN UNBOUNDED ON NULL` syntax:

- https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/8926

It would emulate a hypothetical SQL syntax as follows:

```sql
a BETWEEN UNBOUNDED ON NULL NULL AND NULL
b BETWEEN UNBOUNDED ON NULL NULL AND 10
c BETWEEN UNBOUNDED ON NULL -10 AND NULL
d BETWEEN UNBOUNDED ON NULL -10 AND 10
```

Probably what most people would expect. Until that's implemented out of the box, you'll have to implement it yourself as you suggested, using some sort of "minimum" and "maximum" date that can never appear as an actual date in your system, e.g.

```java
Field<Date> min = inline(Date.valueOf("1970-01-01"));
Field<Date> max = inline(Date.valueOf("9999-12-31"));

Condition c = T.COL.ge(coalesce(from, min)).and(T.COL.le(coalesce(to, max)));
```

Or, implement the coalesce logic in Java, directly:

```java
Condition c = T.COL.ge(from != null ? from : min))
         .and(T.COL.le(to != null ? to : max));
```